# One-liner for printing out the value of a macro from a header

Tags: c, header

I have a header that defines a large number of macros, some of whom depend on other macros -- however, the dependencies are all resolved within this header.

I need a one-liner for printing out the value of a macro defined in that header.

As an example:

```
#define MACRO_A 0x60000000
#define MACRO_B MACRO_A + 0x00010000
//...
```

As a first blush:

```
echo MACRO_B | ${CPREPROCESSOR} --include /path/to/header
```

... which nearly gives me what I want:

```
# A number of lines that are not important
# ...
0x60000000 + 0x00010000
```

... however, I'm trying to keep this from ballooning into a huge sequence of "pipe it to this, then pipe it to that ...".

I've also tried this:

```
echo 'main(){ printf( "0x%X", MACRO_B ); }' \
  | ${CPREPROCESSOR} --include /path/to/header --include /usr/include/stdio.h
```

... but it (the gcc compiler) complains that -E is required when processing code on standard input, so I end up having to write out to a temporary file to compile/run this.

Is there a better way?

-Brian

Comment: Incidentally, it's `int main`, not `void main`.

Comment: @Matteo: Of course, but the point of a one-liner is to keep it terse.

Comment: and `int main` is exactly one character less :) (IIRC the implicit `return 0` is guaranteed by the standard)

Comment: lol.  point taken.  I changed it.

Comment: I didn't realize the return 0 would be added behind the scenes, hence I chose void to avoid compiler errors.

Comment: actually, that's true only for C99 (and C++), in the C89 standard leaving out the `return` there is undefined behavior; on the other hand, `void main` is nonstandard. Anyhow, I think that you'll probably want to encapsulate @Mat's answer in a small shell script, so adding a `return` isn't such a problem. (All this, obviously, is irrelevant nitpickery, "just to talk" :) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo 'void main(){ printf( "0x%X", MACRO_B ); }' \
  | gcc -x c --include /path/to/header --include /usr/include/stdio.h - && ./a.out
```

will do it in one line.

(You misread the error GCC gives when reading from stdin. You need `-E` or `-x` (needed to specify what language is expected))

Also, it's `int main()`, or,  when you don't care like here, just drop the return type entirely. And you don't need to specify the path for `stdio.h`.

So slightly shorter:

```
echo 'main(){printf("0x%X",MACRO_B);}' \
  | gcc -xc --include /path/to/header --include stdio.h - && ./a.out
```

Comment: +1 gah.  I had attempted to leave off the path to stdio.h, but forgot `--include` and didn't realize it until you pointed that out.

Answer (score 1):

What about `tail -n1`? Like this:

```
$ echo C_IRUSR | cpp --include /usr/include/cpio.h | tail -n 1
000400
```

Comment: I don't understand why your answer, or mine, was less "one liner" or less functional than echoing C code into the compiler in two to three times the amount of typing...

Answer (score 0):

How about artificially generating an error that contains your MACRO_B value in it, and then compiling the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to write a small C program, include the header to that, and print the desired output. Then you can use it in your script, makefile or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '"EOF" EOF' | cpp --include /usr/include/stdio.h | grep EOF
```

prints:

```
"EOF" (-1)
```